# Creating Struct node on c++

Tags: c++

I having some doubt with struct.

```
  struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;
    }node; <---- what does this actually do?
```

Thanks.

add on::

Hi, trying to fix this error..

Line 11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
}node;

node* nodeNew(int newData, node* newNext) // line 11
{
    node* n= new node;
    n->data= newData;
    n->next= newNext;
    return n;
}

void listPrint(node* p)
{
    while( p!=NULL )
    {
        cout << p->data << " "; p= p->next;
    }
}

int main()
{


}
```

Is happens when i add that "node" in the struct.

Comment: You said it in your title. Create a node.

Comment: That means you declare a variable called `node` (which has type `node`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final line:

```
}node;
```

creates a variable with the type `struct node`, named `node`. It's equivalent to:

```
  struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
   };
   struct node node;
```

EDIT: In response to your edit, the line:

```
node* nodeNew(int newData, node* newNext)
```

is erroring because `node` isn't a type. Either change it to:

```
struct node* nodeNew(int newData, struct node* newNext)
```

or change the structure declaration to:

```
  typedef struct node node;
  struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
   };
```

Comment: I edited to address your edit. Also, if you found this answer helpful, please consider accepting it (the arrow near the upvote/downvote button).

Comment: Hi Patrick Thanks for the quick response..

I have tried putting "struct node* nodeNew(int newData, node* newNext)" it says Line 11: error: 'node' is not a type.. hmm

Comment: And i tried to execute the nodeNew(int newData, node* newNext) at the main() it wont work.. hmm

Comment: @StevenMeowDeClaude `node` isn't a type, ever. You need to change all the instances of `node*` you have to `struct node*`, including inside `nodeNew` -- but it's going to be easier if you just `typedef` it.

Comment: Alright .. Thank you so much Patrick.. I managed to reduce my bugs.. =D

Answer (score 1):

To be exact, it creates an object from given struct in given scope. Word 'variable' is a too generic term.